# Implementing pagination using Guzzle Services

Tags: guzzle

I'm building a library to consume an API using Guzzle Services. The API gives paginated results, and I'm hoping to handle this at the library level by extending Guzzle (or at least using the most appropriate primitives from Guzzle).

The API uses the [informal "limit and offset"
standard](https://developer.box.com/guides/api-calls/pagination/offset-based/). You give a `limit` key to indicate the number of items requested, and an `offset` key to indicate what index to start the response at. In this case the result also includes keys for the page number (for convenience) and total number of results.

According to [docs from earlier versions](https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/iterators/resource-iterators.html), it was previously possible to implement pagination by overriding `Guzzle\Service\Resource\ResourceIterator` and implementing specific methods and properties. It appears this was removed at some point. Are there any built-in features for this now?

Comment: `The API gives paginated results` how specifically does the api ask for pagination as query string in request?(something similar to how Microsoft Graph api asks for?)

Comment: @bhucho: It uses the informal "limit and offset" approach/standard: https://developer.box.com/guides/api-calls/pagination/offset-based/

I added a description to the question. Thanks :)

Comment: you can use query request params for it if you feel that you are calling it mutiple times then create your own class and create methods setLimit($limit) and setPageSize($pageSize), or extend Guzzle/Client and then add new values to config and call parent contructor but it will be too much effort for simple task